# 'furniture of their pockets"

Tags: meaning-in-context, charles-dickens

> There are many pleasant fictions of the law in constant operation, but there is not one so pleasant or practically humorous as that which supposes every man to be of equal value in its impartial eye, and the benefits of all laws to be equally attainable by all men, without the smallest reference to the **furniture** of their pockets.
>
> [— Charles Dickens, “Nicholas Nickleby”](http://www.poynter.org/how-tos/newsgathering-storytelling/writing-tools/245081/why-these-are-the-ten-best-sentences/)

What does **furniture** mean here? With which of these [definitions](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/furniture?q=furniture) does it comport?

Comment: [**To furnish**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/furnished) *to provide with whatever is necessary for a purpose*. If something is [*too expensive for his pocket*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22too+expensive+for+his+pocket%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), that's because his pocket isn't "equipped/furnished" with ***sufficient money***. In such contexts, the purpose of a gentleman's *pocket* is the same as a lady's *purse* - (i.e. - to pay for things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mildly humorous return to the original sense; *with what [the pockets] are furnished*, or their contents; i.e. how much money you have.  I wouldn't recommend taking up such usages until you have as good an ear for phrases as Dickens had.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please explain, in your answer, how to determine whether this is a "good" phrase? I'm nowhere as skilled as Dickens, yet I didn't even apprehend its meaning, much less use it.

Comment: @LePressentiment- Define what you mean by a "*good*" phrase.

Comment: @Jim In fact, I was referring to "good" in "...until you have as good an ear for phrases as Dickens had." Thus, I mean "good" in that context.